# How do you create an executable jar file in windows? (Without Eclipse)

Tags: java, executable-jar

I've been looking around for how to create an executable jar file in Windows, and everything I'm getting either involves using MacOS or Linux commands, or Eclipse. Are there any other options?

Answer (score 2):

Here is your answer:

> 1. Start Command Prompt.
> 2. Navigate to the folder that holds your class files:
> 3. C:>cd \mywork
> 4. Set path to include JDK’s bin.    For example:
> 5. C:\mywork> path c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin;%path%
> 6. Compile your class(es):
> 7. C:\mywork> javac *.java
> 8. Create a manifest file and your jar file:
> 9. C:\mywork> echo Main-Class: Craps >manifest.txt
> 10. C:\mywork> jar cvfm Craps.jar manifest.txt *.class   or   C:\mywork> jar cvfe Craps.jar Craps *.class
>
> **Test your jar:**
>
> 1. C:\mywork> Craps.jar   or   C:\mywork> java -jar Craps.jar

For more details you can look [here](http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html).

Comment: The part of this that is actually the answer to your question is the "jar" command. That should come with any distribution of the JDK, regardless of operating system, so it is not a "Linux" command. It's a program that you get with whatever JDK distribution you have installled

Answer (score -1):

From Eclipse, Select the project/class, right click, export > java> JAR file.
Sometimes export to a jar file may not be able to run, export to 'Runnable JAR file' instead.

Export java class to jar file directly from command line:
jar -cvf jarFile.jar jarFileClass.class
To create an executable jar file,you need to provide a manifest file and include your Main Class in Manifest.

1. Create MANIFEST.MF file by using any text editor:
   Manifest-version: 1.0
   Main-Class: HelloWorld
2. Execute following jar command to create executable jar
   Java jar -cvfm jarFile.jar MANIFEST.MF jarFileClass.class 
   added manifest

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/03/how-to-create-and-execute-jar-file-in.html#ixzz4B73l9pB8

To run a jar file from command line: java -jar jarFile.jar

Answer (score -2):

I am using [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) in production for 2 years now without single problem on 700+ machines!
You can find the full example [here](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html), but also, you can build exe file directly from maven with [this plugin](https://github.com/lukaszlenart/launch4j-maven-plugin).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12640990)

Comment: @pczeus I have provided the link to the full example which is self explanatory, why would I paste the content here?